# Create multiple ramdisk KMDF

Tags: windows, ram

I have a question about the KMDF Ramdisk sample of Microsoft.

How do create more than one ramdisk device? How will the PnP manager know to call EvtDeviceAdd and can I control how many times it is called?

WdfDeviceCreate() is used to create ramdisk device in RamDiskEvtDeviceAdd(), but I can not install more than one instance of this ramdisk driver.

```
NTSTATUS
RamDiskEvtDeviceAdd(
    IN WDFDRIVER Driver,
    IN PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit
    ) {
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   deviceAttributes;
    NTSTATUS                status;
    WDFDEVICE               device;
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   queueAttributes;
    WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG     ioQueueConfig;
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION       pDeviceExtension;
    PQUEUE_EXTENSION        pQueueContext = NULL;
    WDFQUEUE                queue;
    DECLARE_CONST_UNICODE_STRING(ntDeviceName, NT_DEVICE_NAME);
    DECLARE_CONST_UNICODE_STRING(MY_SDDL_STRING, L"D:P(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;RC)");

    PAGED_CODE();

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);
    // Set name
    status = WdfDeviceInitAssignName(DeviceInit, &ntDeviceName);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }
    // Set permission
    status = WdfDeviceInitAssignSDDLString(DeviceInit, &MY_SDDL_STRING);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {  
        return status;
    }
    WdfDeviceInitSetDeviceType(DeviceInit, FILE_DEVICE_DISK);
    WdfDeviceInitSetIoType(DeviceInit, WdfDeviceIoDirect);
    WdfDeviceInitSetExclusive(DeviceInit, FALSE);

    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_CONTEXT_TYPE(&deviceAttributes, DEVICE_EXTENSION);
    deviceAttributes.EvtCleanupCallback = RamDiskEvtDeviceContextCleanup;

    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, &deviceAttributes, &device);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    pDeviceExtension = DeviceGetExtension(device);

    WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG_INIT_DEFAULT_QUEUE (
        &ioQueueConfig,
        WdfIoQueueDispatchSequential
        );

    ioQueueConfig.EvtIoDeviceControl = RamDiskEvtIoDeviceControl;
    ioQueueConfig.EvtIoRead          = RamDiskEvtIoRead;
    ioQueueConfig.EvtIoWrite         = RamDiskEvtIoWrite;

    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT_CONTEXT_TYPE(&queueAttributes, QUEUE_EXTENSION);

    __analysis_assume(ioQueueConfig.EvtIoStop != 0);
    status = WdfIoQueueCreate( device,
                               &ioQueueConfig,
                               &queueAttributes,
                               &queue );
    __analysis_assume(ioQueueConfig.EvtIoStop == 0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        return status;
    }

    // Context is the Queue handle
    pQueueContext = QueueGetExtension(queue);

    // Set the context for our default queue as our device extension.
    pQueueContext->DeviceExtension = pDeviceExtension;

    // Now do any RAM-Disk specific initialization
    pDeviceExtension->DiskRegInfo.DriveLetter.Buffer =
        (PWSTR) &pDeviceExtension->DriveLetterBuffer;
    pDeviceExtension->DiskRegInfo.DriveLetter.MaximumLength =
        sizeof(pDeviceExtension->DriveLetterBuffer);

    // Get the disk parameters from the registry
    RamDiskQueryDiskRegParameters(
        WdfDriverGetRegistryPath(WdfDeviceGetDriver(device)),
        &pDeviceExtension->DiskRegInfo
        );

    // Allocate memory for the disk image.
    pDeviceExtension->DiskImage = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(
        NonPagedPool,
        pDeviceExtension->DiskRegInfo.DiskSize,
        RAMDISK_TAG
        );

    if (pDeviceExtension->DiskImage) {

        UNICODE_STRING deviceName;
        UNICODE_STRING win32Name;

        RamDiskFormatDisk(pDeviceExtension);

        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

        // Now try to create a symbolic link for the drive letter.
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&win32Name, DOS_DEVICE_NAME);
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&deviceName, NT_DEVICE_NAME);

        pDeviceExtension->SymbolicLink.Buffer = (PWSTR)
            &pDeviceExtension->DosDeviceNameBuffer;
        pDeviceExtension->SymbolicLink.MaximumLength =
            sizeof(pDeviceExtension->DosDeviceNameBuffer);
        pDeviceExtension->SymbolicLink.Length = win32Name.Length;

        RtlCopyUnicodeString(&pDeviceExtension->SymbolicLink, &win32Name);
        RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString(&pDeviceExtension->SymbolicLink,
                                       &pDeviceExtension->DiskRegInfo.DriveLetter);

        status = WdfDeviceCreateSymbolicLink(device,
                                             &pDeviceExtension->SymbolicLink);
    }

    return status;
```

Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Welcome.  Please provide an example of what you are trying to do so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old post, but since there are no useful answers, I thought I might add my thoughts.

`EvtDeviceAdd` is called by the KMDF framework when a device matches a hardware ID that your INF supports. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

According to the VirtualVolume documentation (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/VirtualVolume-83334efd), the only way to create a device is to call `devcon install virtvol.inf virtvol`.

You can make multiple RAMDisks by calling `devcon install` multiple times.